# What is the proper way of autoincrementing non primary key column?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a table which has an integer field which is supposed to be unique and autoincremented.

After doing some research I came up with two different approaches:

**Case A**

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<MyTable>()
                .Property(x => x.MyIntegerField)
                .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                .Metadata.SetAfterSaveBehavior(PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore);

            modelBuilder.Entity<MyTable>()
                .HasIndex(x => x.MyIntegerField)
                .IsUnique();
```

This works, but I have questions regarding it:

- When does it increment the value of the **MyIntegerField**?
- Does it create it on the app level or on the database level?

  I ask this is because imagine two different HTTP requests are coming to the app. I'm afraid it might throw `UniqueConstraint exception` if value generation happened on app-level.

**Case B**

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<MyTable>()
                .Property(x => x.MyIntegerField)
                .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                .UseIdentityColumn();

            modelBuilder.Entity<MyTable>()
                .HasIndex(x => x.MyIntegerField)
                .IsUnique();
```

This works too, but the again I have questions:

- Does this make the field managed on the database level?

  In the docs it says `UseIdentityColumn()` is **for primary keys**, but MyIntegerField is not a primary key. I did not mark it as one, and in the schema after migration I see it didn't create it as one.
- Are there any possible problems I might face using this method?

What is the correct way of solving my issue?

I am using GUID for primary key

Comment: I am not sure but meanwhile you could take a look at the generated SQL [Debug Ef Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/)

Comment: There is no reason that an Identity (autoincrementing) column must be a primary key. There is no reason that a unique column must be a primary key.

Comment: @Nick.Mc I am talking about EF Core. Quote from docs for UseIdentityColumn():  "Configures the key property to use the SQL Server IDENTITY feature to generate values for new entities, when targeting SQL Server."

Comment: @theuserthatpretendstobesmart don't use EF Core to manage the database. EF is an ORM - Object to Relational Mapper, not a DB administration library. Migrations can only go so far. `IDENTITY` in SQL Serve can be used with *any* field, not just primary keys. You can also use SEQUENCE objects to provide incrementing default values for rows. EF Core's only specifies that the column has the IDENTITY attribute, it doesn't make it a PK.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the tables that have been created by this process in SSMS. If the field in question is an identity then it's a database level assignment and you don't need to worry about duplicates being created

Comment: With regards to case B1: _Does this make the field managed on the Database level?_ going by the doco, yes, it's sets the column to be an identity which means the db takes care of reliably generating a unique incrementing integer key. I couldn't see in the docs where it said it had to be a primary key though

Comment: Case B2: _Are there any possible problems I might face using this method_ No, but it's a code smell to have two seperate generated unique identifiers in one table.

Comment: @Nick.Mc Why would they write explicitly "Configures the key property to use the SQL Server IDENTITY feature" in the docs? I mean why key property? Because of code smell, or because there might be a problem when using with nonkey property?

Comment: @Nick.Mc And if I don't use Identity, does Case A do the increment operation in app level, or in db level

Comment: Yes I do see "key property" all through that page, but a "key property" is not a "primary key". I guess by "key property" they might mean "a column that holds unique values" but I can't be sure. For Case A, I read some of the doco but couldn't really make sense of it. The quickest way to be certain is check the table that has been created. If that column is an IDENTITY, then the value will be generated by the DB.

Comment: @Nick.Mc done. please see answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like both do the same... I tested both cases, and checked for Identity column using the following command:

```
SELECT 
    c.name AS ColumnName,
    t.name AS TableName,
    CASE 
        WHEN c.is_identity = 1 THEN 'Yes'
        ELSE 'No'
    END AS IsIdentityColumn
FROM sys.columns c
INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE 
    c.name = 'My column'  -- Replace with your column name
    AND t.name = 'My table'  -- Replace with your table name
    AND t.schema_id = SCHEMA_ID('dbo');  -- Specify the schema (dbo in this case)
```

It resulted with **Yes** in both cases
Now I don't know why exactly they mentioned "for key properties" in docs for *UseIdentityColumn()* method, but both seem to be working the same way. Creating an **Identity** inside the DB, which means DB itself is gonna manage the insert values.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a quick experiment trying out the second approach.

Those are versions of packages I used:

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design Version="7.0.11"
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer Version="7.0.11"

I started with this DbContext:

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Test;

public class CustomDbContext : DbContext
{
    public class CustomEntity
    {
        required public int Id { get; set; }
        required public string Name { get; set; }
        required public int Incremental { get; set; }
    }

    public CustomDbContext(DbContextOptions<CustomDbContext> options)
    : base(options)
    {
        
    }

    public DbSet<CustomEntity> CustomEntities { get; set; } = null!
}
```

And created a fresh migration using `dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate` getting this migration file:

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

#nullable disable

namespace Test.Migrations
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public partial class InitialCreate : Migration
    {
        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "CustomEntities",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false),
                    Incremental = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_CustomEntities", x => x.Id);
                });
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "CustomEntities");
        }
    }
}
```

Now I changed the DbContext by overloading `OnModelCreating` method:

```cs
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomEntity>()
                .Property(x => x.Incremental)
                .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                .UseIdentityColumn();
    }
```

now calling `dotnet ef migrations add Incremental` resulted in an error:

> The properties 'CustomEntity.Id', 'CustomEntity.Incremental' are configured to use 'Identity' value generation and are mapped to the same table 'CustomEntities', but only one column per table can be configured as 'Identity'. Call 'ValueGeneratedNever' in 'OnModelCreating' for properties that should not use 'Identity'.

It seems like ChatGPT was lying once again, and this approach is not valid for code first. It should be possible to do it when working in database first though since nothing prevents you from manually adding a second identity column to a table. I think you are stuck with solving the problem on C# side.

Comment: I don't get that error, because I use GUID for PK. Maybe I should have mentioned that in the question sorry

Comment: In all fairness you should have provided us with "minimal reproducible example" :) Using GUIDs for PKs is a very common malpractice. SQL Server can't do much of its internal optimizations when working on GUID as a PK. It's advised to use GUID as a "fake key" for C# logic, but also inject in `OnModelCreating` an `Id` key that will act as physical key for SQLServer innards.

Comment: The question was not about whether I should be using Guid or Int for PK. And I don't understand what minimal rewproducible example you are demanding. It is not a "I have a bug in my code" question. It is a question about which option does what and suits better in context of making field autoincremented and unique.

Comment: FYI you can't have multiple identity columns in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

I have answered previously for a problem when Id is also an identity column, now I'm answering for a case when Id is a `Guid`.

This is the DbContext I used:

```cs
public class CustomDbContext : DbContext
{
    public class CustomEntity
    {
        required public Guid Id { get; set; }
        required public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Incremental { get; set; }
    }

    public CustomDbContext(DbContextOptions<CustomDbContext> options)
    : base(options)
    {
        
    }

    public DbSet<CustomEntity> CustomEntities { get; set; } = null!;

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomEntity>()
                .Property(x => x.Incremental)
                .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                .UseIdentityColumn();
    }
}
```

And this is a part of migration script I got from it:

```cs
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "CustomEntities",
        columns: table => new
        {
            Id = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false),
            Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false),
            Incremental = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1")
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("PK_CustomEntities", x => x.Id);
        });
}
```

now I tried getting the client side `Incremental` value into the database:

```cs
app.MapGet("/api/hello", (CustomDbContext ctx) =>
{
    ctx.Database.EnsureDeleted();
    ctx.Database.EnsureCreated();

    ctx.Add(new CustomDbContext.CustomEntity()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
        Name = "Incremental Provided",
        Incremental = 616
    });

    ctx.SaveChanges();

    return new { Message = "Hello World!" };
});
```

I got an exception.

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'CustomEntities' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

All was fine when I didn't provide the `Incremental` value.

```cs
ctx.Add(new CustomDbContext.CustomEntity()
{
    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
    Name = "Incremental Provided"
});
```

The Query sent to the database on `SaveChanges` looked correct.

```sql
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF;
SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO [CustomEntities] ([Id], [Name])
OUTPUT INSERTED.[Incremental]
VALUES (@p0, @p1);
```

The DbContext created the row. Allowed `Incremental` to be filled by the identity logic from inside the SQL Server, and query ended with returning the `Incremental` value from the database back to DbContext. So after `SaveChanges` the entity within C# should have updated value.

And it seems like it does.

```cs
var entity = new CustomDbContext.CustomEntity()
{
    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
    Name = "Incremental Provided"
};

ctx.Add(entity);
Console.WriteLine($"Before SaveChanges - {entity.Incremental}");
ctx.SaveChanges();
Console.WriteLine($"After SaveChanges - {entity.Incremental}");
```

```
Before SaveChanges = 0
(...)
After SaveChanges = 1
```

In conclusion. Second approach looks completely correct and safe. You will not end up with duplicate values inside the identity column even in case of a race condition since EFCore is simply letting SqlServer handle it with its internal mechanisms.